# How to calculate the minimum of the dates of two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL 5.7 query that tells me how many people connected themselves or read an email at least a year ago.

```
select lang, count(distinct user_id)
from ((select user_id, lang
       from sessions
       where session_time > now() - interval 1 year
      ) union all
      (select user_id, lang
       from unique_open_emails
       where date > now() - interval 1 year
      )
     ) u
group by lang;
```

I would like to update it with Python in order to do this calculation every day until the very last date in either the one or the other table. So I did:

```
with db as c:
    info("Creating table and populating `alive_subscribers` ...")
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alive_subscribers Date AS DATE,
                                                              Lang AS CHAR(2),
                                                              Count AS INTEGER;""")

    sdate = c.execute(
        """
        SELECT MIN(date_email, date_activity) FROM 
            (
                SELECT date FROM unique_open_emails
                ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1;
            ) AS date_email,
            (
                SELECT session_time FROM sessions
                ORDER BY session_time ASC LIMIT 1;
            ) AS date_activity
        )"""
    )  # start date
    edate = date.now()
    date_list = pd.date_range(sdate,edate-timedelta(days=1),freq='d')
    for date_range in date_list:
        c.execute(
            f"""
            insert into ...
            select lang, count(distinct user_id)
            from ((select user_id, lang
                   from sessions
                   where session_time > now() - interval 1 year
                  ) union all
                  (select user_id, lang
                   from unique_open_emails
                   where date > {date_range} - interval 1 year
                  )
                 ) u
            group by lang;""")
```

But it returns an error when I try to get the minimum of the dates of the two databases:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' date_activity) FROM 
    (
        SELECT date FROM unique_open_emails
        ' at line 1
```

Here is the [MySQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3b53543deb351de009231b702343eec6) and the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`App Type` varchar(11), `Lang` varchar(2), `Session ID` int, `session_time` datetime, `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO sessions
    (`App Type`, `Lang`, `Session ID`, `session_time`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    #july 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1193745),
    # june 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 12345),
    # june 2020
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 54321)
;

SELECT * FROM sessions;

CREATE TABLE unique_open_emails
    (`date` datetime, `lang` varchar(2), `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO unique_open_emails
    (`date`, `lang`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    ('2016-04-12 00:00:00', 'fr', 115434),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11357),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137481),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10296),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 125772),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 955480),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9269),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90716),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 26330),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87416),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88358),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 102515),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89867),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119146),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 133316),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90095),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16510),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 21530),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81581),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'es', 54321),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 29363),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90326),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 23961),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89000),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9484),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11845),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 41231),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 588),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16678),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 19674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130113),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 84719),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 123252),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4676),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17452),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136544),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15917),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 82787),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81620),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 135298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15643),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 80981),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 51827),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90554),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10277),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24432),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6651),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 64106),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119080),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 72659),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130004),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 22320),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136966),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11317),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 79031),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90800),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16149),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61463),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 5383),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10223),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88100),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91691),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 126),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86858),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1419),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89849),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15721),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86444),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130822),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 73991),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113969),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16779),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 71267),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61067),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89081),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24815),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91928),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 13071),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1942),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44012),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 52049),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6626),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7034),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 20442),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 75422),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16673),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17325),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7898),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 85226),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136557),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 134423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 68723),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'en', 118331),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136046),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136891),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9169),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88946),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 115919),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44492),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89783),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137482),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 38636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11227),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 108310),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4700),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17976),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 8580),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91316)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure what you expect, but you ha a lot of errors

Min doesn't have more than one value, and semicolin belong onl yat the end of a query

> ```
>        SELECT IF(date < session_time,date, session_time) as date FROM 
>             (
>                 SELECT date FROM unique_open_emails
>                 ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
>             ) AS date_email,
>             (
>                 SELECT session_time FROM sessions
>                 ORDER BY session_time ASC LIMIT 1
>             ) AS date_activity
> ```
>
> ```
> | date                |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2016-04-12 00:00:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d929ade3b2233eb205df9c394b3e60b)*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MIN, can you use something like :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_1<date_2 THEN date_1 ELSE date_2 END FROM Table
```